# Missing urlTemplateRewrite field in REST API of Create Operation in Azure API Management Service

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I am trying to use Azure API Management Service using REST API. I want to create / update API Operations using REST API. I referred to [Create New Operation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn781423.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#CreateOperation) documentation and found that property for "Rewrite URL Template" field.

I want to create / update a new Operation which has name, method, urlTemplate, urlTemplateRewrite and description properties.

Can someone suggest on how urlTemplateRewrite property can be populated using REST API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to discussion here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/b2dae2eb-27d8-46cb-bf0f-571ef1f44efe/unable-to-create-new-api-operations-using-rest-api-missing-urltemplaterewrite-field-in-rest-api?forum=azureapimgmt